# Certain isotypical component of the tensor product of irreducible representations of $\mathrm{U}(n)$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, lie-groups, tensor-products

The following question is closely related to [this one](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/398071/multiplicities-of-irreducible-un-modules-in-the-tensor-product-v-lambda).

Let $\mathrm{U}(n)$ be the group of all (complex) unitary matrices $n\times n$. It is known that all irreducible representations of $\mathrm{U}(n)$ are parameterized by weights $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_n)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$, where $\lambda_1\ge \lambda_1\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_n$; denote this representation by $V_{\lambda}$.
It also worths mentioning that if all $\lambda_i\ge 0$, then the corresponding irreducible representation is just $\mathbb{S}^{\lambda}(V)$, where $V\simeq\mathbb{C}^n$ is the standard $n$-dimensional representation. Similarly, if all $\lambda_i\le 0$, then $V_{\lambda}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{\mu}(V)^*$, where $\mu=(-\lambda_n,\ldots,-\lambda_1)$. Here $\mathbb{S}^{\mu}$ is the Schur functor associated to a partition $\mu$.

Now suppose that we have two decreasing sequences of integers: $\lambda=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_l)$ and $\mu=(\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k)$, where $\lambda_1\ge\ldots\ge\lambda_l\ge 0\ge\mu_1\ge\ldots\ge\mu_k$ and $k+l\le n$. We are interested in $V_{(\lambda,\mu)}$-isotypic component of the tensor product $V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}$ which can be regarded as a submodule of $V^{\otimes|\lambda|}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes|\mu|}$. Here $|\lambda|=\sum_{j=1}^{l}\lambda_j$, $|\mu|=\sum_{j=1}^{k}(-\mu_j)$ and weight $(\lambda,\mu)\in\mathbb{Z}^n$ is defined as
$$
(\lambda,\mu)=(\lambda_1,\ldots,\lambda_l,\underbrace{0,\ldots,0}_{n-k-l~\text{zeroes}},\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_k).
$$

I think that I saw somewhere the following statement (probably it was in The Classical Groups by H. Weyl but I am not sure and now I can't find this statement there).

**Claim.** The $V_{(\lambda,\mu)}$-isotypic component of $V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}$ is the intersection of kernels of all tensor contractions $\psi_{p,q}$, where $p=\overline{1,|\lambda|}$ and $q=\overline{1,|\mu|}$, that correspond to the $p$-th contravariant component and to the $q$-th covariant component.

Does anyone know whether this statement is correct or not? Of course I could have forgotten some details, so any similar facts (or corrections to the original statement) would be appreciated.

**Update.** It seems that a similar fact is claimed in A. Kirillov's *Elements of the theory of representations* (see 17.2. Representations of classical compact Lie groups) but the author also refers to H. Weyl's Classical groups without any additional details. Hence, any other references would be appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand the notation  "$p=\overline{1,|\lambda|}$ and $q=\overline{1,|\mu|}$."

Comment: @BenWebster By something like "where $i=\overline{1,n}$" I meant "where $i$ runs over $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$". Anyway, thanks a lot for your answer -- I will look into reference you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true.  Let $r=|\lambda|,s=|\mu|$.  The important observations are this:

- $V_{(\lambda,\mu)}$ appears with multiplicity 1.  It's the "Cartan component" of the tensor product.
- $V_{(\lambda,\mu)}$ is not a summand of $V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1}$.  This can be seen by some basic convexity results (or just the Pieri rule).  Thus, it lies in the kernel of any map to this space.
- Any other summand of $V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}$ is a summand of $V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1}$.  This is actually probably the trickiest part.  There should be some nice combinatorial way to see this, but at the moment, the only way I can see is the Schur-Weyl duality with the walled Brauer algebra ([See here, for example](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0709.0851.pdf)). By eq. (2) in that paper, any endomorphism of $V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}$ must be a scalar plus a homomorphism factoring through $V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1}$.  Applying this to projection to any summand other than $V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}$ shows that summand is isomorphic to one of $V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1}$.
- Any homomorphism $ V_{\lambda}\otimes V_{\mu}\to V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1}$ factors through one of the vector contractions.  Again, I would show this using the walled Brauer algebra (or maybe better, the oriented Brauer category of [this paper](https://pages.uoregon.edu/brundan/papers/AOB.pdf)), since $\mathrm{Hom}(V^{\otimes r}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s},V^{\otimes r-1}\otimes (V^*)^{\otimes s-1})$ is an easily understood bimodule of diagrams, and you just have to shorten one of the cups (in the usual graphical calculus, a contraction is a cup joining two inputs with nothing else happening).